# How can I increase page load speed?

Tags: django

I need to have multilingual site. For this purpose I wrote django module, which collects lots of info about countries, cities and their translations to almost all languages.

Below is the short version of models of this module:

```
class LanguagesGroups(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Language Group'

class Languages(models.Model):
    iso_code = models.CharField("ISO Code", max_length=14, db_index=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(LanguagesGroups, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Group of ISO',
                              related_name='group', db_index=True)

class Cities(models.Model):
    population = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    territory_km2 = models.IntegerField(null=True)


class CitiesTranslations(models.Model):
    common_name = models.CharField(max_length=188, db_index=True)

    city = models.ForeignKey(Cities, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Details of City')
    lang_group = models.ForeignKey(LanguagesGroups, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Language of city',
                                   null=True)

    class Meta:
        index_together = (['common_name', 'city'],
                          ['city', 'lang_group'])
```

I want to show to users some data about places which user requested with translated versions of cities (depending on user settings):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=120)
    info = models.TextField(_('information'), max_length=1500, blank=True)

    city = models.ForeignKey(Cities, verbose_name=_('city'), null=True, blank=True)

    def get_city(self):
        user_lang = get_language()  # en
        lang_group = Languages.objects.get(iso_code=user_lang).group  # 1823

        return CitiesTranslations.objects.get(city=self.city, lang_group=lang_group).common_name
```

template.html

```
{% for item in object_list %}
    {{ item.title }}
    {{ item.get_city }}
    {{ item.info }}
{% endfor %}
```

When I add `{{ item.get_city }}`, in case of pagination and just 25 items per page, the page load speed goes down up to 18 times and amount of queries (according to django-debug-tool) goes up from 2 to 102. django-debug-tool tells me about 25 duplications.

How can I fix this slowness?

**EDIT:**
My view

```
class ProfileListView(ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profiles/profiles_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'places_list'
    paginate_by = 25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want speed - you should try [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/).

You can also optimize your query.

```
def get_city(self):
    user_lang = get_language()  # en
    return CitiesTranslations.objects.get(
        city=self.city_id, lang_group__group__iso_code=user_lang
    ).common_name
```

What you probably also want is to get all your stuff in batches, not with individual method calls. Assuming we have your `object_list`:

```
city_ids = [x.city_id for x in object_list]
city_translations = CitiesTranslations.objects.filter(
    city__in=city_ids, lang_group__group__iso_code=user_lang
).values_list('city_id', 'common_name')
city_translations = dict(city_translations)
for obj in object_list:
    obj.city_name = city_translations[obj.city_id]
```

You can put this code somewhere in your view. You will also have to change `{{ item.get_city }}` to `{{ item.city_name }}` in the templates.

Comment: You probably meant `...__iso_code=user_lang` instead of `...__iso_code=lang_group`. This decreased queries from 102 to 52. Not bad. Regarding "What you probably also want is to get all your stuff in batches, not with individual method calls." - probably this is what I need :) Could you recommend anything, how to put this stuff in batches?

Comment: @TitanFighter You can use `.get(city=self.city_id, ...)` to save a query, or if you need the city later on, you can use `Profile.objects.select_related('city')` in your original query. The first will use the local foreign key value instead of fetching the related object. The second one will use a join to fetch the city in the same query that fetches the profiles.

Comment: @knbk Thank you. Your 1st method in combination with Назар's answer gives me 27 queries. I forgot about `city_id` trick :)

Comment: @TitanFighter Regarding your question about batches - we have to know, how do you get your peculiar `object_list` to give some hints about that.

Comment: @НазарТопольський, I added the code of my view, so nothing special - just use CBV without overriding any methods.

Comment: @TitanFighter kinda late, but I added the sample code for batch processing.

Comment: @НазарТопольський Thanks a lot! 5 queries vs 27 queries; 250 ms CPU time vs 690 ms